# How to enable intellisense on Xamarin.Android's AXML?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Since this great tool became free for everyone, I tried it, and I liked it especially Visual Studio Android emulator.

But, I got a problem because Visual Studio intellisense does not work at all for axml files.

I tried this article (https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files-) but those files (android-layout-xml.xsd, schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd) does not exist in my PC

Answer (score 12):

1. Download this two files (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/master/android-layout-xml.xsd) to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android" (if there is no such files there).
2. Start "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015"
3. Execute "devenv /resetsettings"
4. Open *.axml file in your solution with "Open with" and select "Automatic editor selector (XML)"
   [image: Automatic editor selector (XML)]
5. If intellisence still not working go to XML -> Schemas, add this schemas manually and restart visual studio.
6. Enjoy!
   [image: Intellisenseworks]

Comment: Steps 1+2+3 were enough for me to make it work. Thank you very much, it was not easy to find the correct fix.

Answer (score 4):

The XSD files are located at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\schemas*, note that this path exist when you install the Xamarin Studio.

I guess, we don't ship these files with Visual Studio plugin, I will have to confirm this with Xamarin.Android team.

Meantime you can find the schema files at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180685/#Comment_180685

Comment: Yes, the schema files were included in the Xamarin Studio install for Windows, but not in the Visual Studio Plug-in.  So now that Xamarin Studio is no longer included in the Windows install, the schema files are never present.  It would be nice the schema files would be included in the VS plugin :)

Comment: @SharpMobileCode yeah, I am going to bring this up with the VS team :)

Comment: I copied those files to that location but I can't make the intellisense work