# How to enable intellisense for axml files in Visual Studio-Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin development for android but I have some experience in developing apps with Android Studio. My problem is that there is no suggestion in XML my layout files. This makes the development process slower. I guess there must be a way to enable suggestion (Auto Complete) for VS. (This feature is enabled by default in Android Studio and Eclipse So why it's not enabled in VS by default?)

I Also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744804/2101822) but I don't know how to do this line:

> Start "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015"

the answer is not clear enough about that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable intellisense on Xamarin.Android's AXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579565/how-to-enable-intellisense-on-xamarin-androids-axml)

Comment: @AkashAmin I've Edited my question and explained about the exact step that I have problem with ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to download some schemas and load them into VS to enable intellisense.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744804/4038191) for the details. Don't forget to upvote that answer if it helped!

The [Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.1 Release](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.1/#androidxml) also includes *some* (WIP) support for VS XML features, although I'm really hyped for the [4.2 release](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Android_Designer)! You can install 4.2 by switching to the Preview or Alpha updater channels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. just one question: i dont know how to do number 2 of the answer you've mentioned. could you please explain more about that?

Comment: @Milad All I actually did was the 5th step. That worked for me. I'm sorry I can't help you out more right now because my dev machine has gone to the workshop and I'm currently on a Mac (unfortunately). Try *only* the 5th step after downloading the files.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm going to try that after finding those files on the net. unfortunately both links are not working for me ;)

Comment: Hmm. They seem to be working fine for me. Does [this](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd) work for you?

Comment: Found those files somewhere else :D https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd

Comment: @Milad technically it's the same file, but great! Let me know if the 5th step works.